# Oracle BI Publisher rtf template with output to Excel and injecting a VBA macro

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

When creating an Oracle BI Publisher rdf template in Microsoft Word, with intended output to Microsoft Excel; is there a way to inject an Excel VBA macro in the Excel output file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RTF template does not support a macro, which means even you put some macro in the template, it will be lost during report generation.
However, you can create an Excel template and put some macro in it. The macro will be available in generated Excel file.

Comment: The only template types are: eText - Inbound, eText - Outbound, PDF, RTF, XSL-FO, XSL-HTML, XSL-TEXT, XSL-XML. So how does one use an Excel file as a template? The only one I know is RTF, do you have some links for the other types?

Comment: Excel files are supported as BI Publisher templates. You can refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/bi.1111/e13881/T527073T571887.htm) to create an Excel template.

Comment: I'm on R12 not Fusion. So can I still use Excel templates? Which of the template types I listed would I use then for my template type when I upload the Excel template into the R12 application?

Comment: While I'm more familiar with Fusion than R12, I think which template type it supported is a BI Publisher issue. Fusion/R12 generates the data for report and BI Publisher combine the data with template to generate the report. So you can try to create a simple Excel template and upload it to BI Publisher to generate a report.